# Visual Studio 2013: What controls the syntax highlighting and auto formatting I'm seeing in hlsl and fx files?

Tags: directx, visual-studio-2013, syntax-highlighting

In Visual Studio 2013, `.hlsl` and `.fx` files have basic syntax highlighting, and when I close curly braces, I get simple automatic curly brace formatting and for some reason it also inserts semicolons at the end of the curly braces. It doesn't need to insert the semicolons, so I looked through the settings to try and find where to change the formatting settings, but there is absolutely nothing I can find, either in the main settings list (such as with "Web Essentials") or in any subcategory (particularly "Text Editor"). I also looked in "Add-in Manager", which was empty, and in "Extensions and Updates", which has absolutely nothing relevant.

I'm using Visual Studio 2013, I have the Windows 8.1 SDK installed (as it provides the DirectX SDK components now). I also have the MonoGame SDK installed, but I have never used it.

[image: syntax highlighting]

[image: settings]

[image: extensions]

Comment: Were you able to figure out where it is?  I'm seeing this, too, and am also curious.

Comment: @JayLemmon Nope, still no idea...

Answer (score 2):

It appears as though HLSL formatting and syntax awareness are "piggybacking" on C++. My evidence is this:

1. If you change the C++ formatting options (Tools/Options/TextEditor/C++) and experiment with toggling the automatic formatting on and off, you'll see that those settings also apply to HLSL.
2. There was a bug a couple years ago (reported here http://nshader.codeplex.com/) where a particular version of Nvidia Parallel Nsight would cause VS2012 to syntax-color HLSL as if it were C++.